# How to get the memory a function consumes

Tags: memory, function

Our application consumes lots of memory and we need to identify which function cause the maximum usage of the memory. Is their any way or even any existing tool to do this(Windows, Native)?

**Here is the environment:**

Windows Xp

VS2008

Native C++ (MFC Based)

Thanks so much.

Comment: It's important to know what language/framework/platform/runtime your application is built with.

Comment: What development tools are you using? What language? What are the components of the application? Have you tried Google? You need to put a bit more effort into your question so we can help you

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, these information are provided now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 Team System you can use the [built-in memory allocation](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/10/09/using-vsts-2008-memory-allocation-profiling.aspx) profiler.  Here's a good MSDN article, [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) using VS2008. There is also a profiler [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/profiler/).

[RedGate's ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ANTS_Profiler/index.htm?gclid=CMLElISKwpkCFRxNagodFBUXuQ)

[MemProfiler](http://memprofiler.com/)

[ValGrind](http://valgrind.org/) (free)

EDIT: since you updated to indicate C++, please also see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292457/profiler-for-visual-studio-2008-c).

See Also:

[.NET Memory Profiling Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/-net-memory-profiling-tools)

[Does anyone here have a favorite memory profiling/memory leak tool they like to use for their java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642/does-anyone-here-have-a-favorite-memory-profiling-memory-leak-tool-they-like-to-u)

[Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-dotnet-memory-and-performance-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiler. such as Automated QA's AQTime - http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/index.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Most tools/profilers operate only on .NET apps which in your case is n/a

I've used Boundschecker and Purify to check for memory leaks/memory profiling for native applications (they got trial versions AFAIK) but you can also use the built in functions for this purpose if you are just interested in a one-shot analysis

look for _crtCheckMemory in your online help for a starting location.