# Why do I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError given the size of my file?

Tags: java, performance

I'm parsing a 328kb text file and storing the content in a java List.

This is the command line (I'm supposed to use 1GB ram given the parameters).

```
java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -cp .:jars/* CentroidGenerator data/data.xml
```

However I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

This is the code, I've commented most of it for debugging: http://d.pr/pRxe
thanks

Comment: If parsing a 328kb file gives you `OutOfMemoryError`s, you are doing it wrong. Unfortunately, my glassball is in the shop until next tuesday so please show us your code.

Comment: @Bombe I've already added the link!

Comment: Most probably you have endless loop somewhere in your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryError exception: Java heap space, how to debug... ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422762/outofmemoryerror-exception-java-heap-space-how-to-debug)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, this bit looks wrong to me:

```
for (int i=0; i<centroids.size(); i++) {            
    Centroid centroid = new Centroid(...);
    // Some other code here
    centroids.add(centroid);
}
```

So suppose `centroids` has a size of 1. In the first iteration of the loop, `i` is 0, which is less than 1. You create a new instance of `Centroid`, add it to the list, and continue. Now `i` is 1, but now `centroids.size()` is 2, so you keep going... etc.

Basically, this loop isn't going to stop until you run out of memory.

It's not clear to me what you're *trying* to do in the loop, but you don't want to do what you *are* doing...

Comment: Very good. Had seen the code also, but, doing mostly functional programming, did not even consider that the size of a collection could change while iterating over it ...